# Linear regression using groupby and sklearn: How do I save the results of model.score in a new dataframe with the associated group name?

Tags: group-by, type-conversion, linear-regression

I have a dataset with 99 groups. Below is an example subset containing three groups.

```
Name  conc  height
0  Oxaloacetate    20    9047
1  Oxaloacetate    50   24966
2  Oxaloacetate   100   47028
3   L-Glutamine    50  492567
4   L-Glutamine   100  553082
5   L-Glutamine    20  202931
6      L-Lysine    50  334892
7      L-Lysine   100  367027
8      L-Lysine    20  155603
```

My aim was to generate the individual R2 score for each group based on linear regression. I have performed linear regression on each individual group using groupby and sklearn LinearRegression using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To visualize
import pandas as pd  # To read data
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv ('name.csv')
```

```
def regress(df, X, y):
    model = LinearRegression()
    X = df.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    y = df.iloc[:, 2].values.reshape(-1, 1)
    model.fit(X, y)
    r_squared = model.score(X, y)
    print(r_squared)
```

```
df.groupby('Name').apply(regress, y, X)
```

This generates the following output:

```
0.7663021592216027
0.7484017413491248
0.9974783003289882
```

I would like to generate a new dataset containing the Compound name and the corresponding R2 score, i.e.:

```
Name  R2
0  Oxaloacetate    0.7663021592216027
1   L-Glutamine    0.7484017413491248
2      L-Lysine    0.9974783003289882
```

However, I can't work out how to convert the output from `model.score` to a pandas dataframe, or how to achieve this within the `groupby` function.

Any help achieving this would be greatly appreciated! Sorry in advance if this is a duplicate question, but I've spent about 2 hours looking through other questions on here and haven't found the answer. As a beginner, I think it can sometimes be difficult to extract the information needed from previous, similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Load data:

```
import pandas as pd

#Load data
data = {
    'Name': ['Oxaloacetate', 'Oxaloacetate', 'Oxaloacetate',
             'L-Glutamine', 'L-Glutamine', 'L-Glutamine',
             'L-Lysine', 'L-Lysine', 'L-Lysine'],
    'conc': [20, 50, 100, 50, 100, 20, 50, 100, 20],
    'height': [9047, 24966, 47028, 492567, 553082, 202931, 334892, 367027, 155603]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The main change below is that it *returns* the score. Other changes are optional.

```
#Regression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # To visualize
import pandas as pd  # To read data
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def regress(X, y):
    X_a = X.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
    y_a = y.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
    r_squared = LinearRegression().fit(X_a, y_a).score(X_a, y_a)
    # print(r_squared)
    return r_squared
```

Return R2 per group and put it into a new dataframe:

```
#R2 per name, and put it in a new dataframe
r2_df = (
    df
    .groupby('Name')
    .apply(lambda group: regress(group['conc'], group['height']))
    #Rename the resulting series to 'R2'
    .rename('R2')
    #Convert it to a dataframe with an index of "Name" and a column of "R2"
    .to_frame()
)
r2_df
```

---

Query in comments about the `lambda` function. Lambda functions are a compact way of defining a function in a single line. In this case, the function I've defined takes an input that I've named `groups`, and returns the output from `regress(...)`. I've named the input `groups` because by the time we get to `.apply()`, pandas will be supplying a dataframe on a group-by-group basis (e.g. first L-Glutamine, then L-Lysine, etc). The lambda function takes that dataframe in (now called `group`), accesses its `conc` and `height` columns, and supplies it to `regress()`. This happens for each `Name` you've grouped by.

You can visualise what lambda function is getting as follows:

```
(
    df
    .groupby('Name')
    .apply(lambda group: print('input is:', group.name, '\n', group))
)
```

Which prints:

[image]

As you can see, `pandas` cycles through 3 times, one for each name it found. Each time, the lambda function is supplied a dataframe that's limited to the rows for that name. The lambda function reads off the column values, supplies it to regress, and you get R2 back for each time.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! Could I ask why you added lambda group? I've had a quick google but I'm not clear what the advantage is of including it.

Comment: No worries, glad it worked as needed. Please see my updated answer for an explanation of the `lambda` function. Happy to provide further clarification if wanted.